# How to pan on scroll in d3 v4/v5 with Canvas

Tags: javascript, d3.js, canvas

#### Background

I'm rendering many elements, so I'm using d3 with canvas instead of SVG.

[This lovely block from @mbostock describes how to zoom the canvas on mouse scroll in d3v4](https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/d1f7b58631e71fbf9c568345ee04a60e). However, I'd like to *pan* on mouse scroll instead of zooming (like regular webpages and [this block](http://bl.ocks.org/ahmohamed/82ac20ccc949470e3206)).

There are a [couple](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46568677/d3-v4-pan-with-mouse-wheel) [folks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28603796/d3-remap-mousewheel-to-be-panning-gesture-instead-of-zoom-gesture) who have figured out how to pan on scroll using d3 with SVGs. Unfortunately, those answers don't work out of the box for canvas.

#### Code

```
canvas.call(d3.zoom()
              .scaleExtent([1 / 2, 4])
              .on("zoom", zoomed));
```

...  later on ...

```
function zoomed() {
  context.save();
  context.clearRect(0, 0, w, h);

  // this gives the default zooming and panning behavior in canvas:
  context.translate(d3.event.transform.x, d3.event.transform.y);
  context.scale(d3.event.transform.k, d3.event.transform.k);

  // Instead, something like this might work?:
  current_translate = d3....?
  new_translate = {'x': current_translate.x + d3.event.sourceEvent.wheelDeltaX, 
                   'y': current_translate.y + d3.event.sourceEvent.wheelDeltaY};
  context.translate(new_translate.x, new_translate.y);

  drawCanvas();
  context.restore();
}
```

Alternately, it might be the case I shouldn't use using `d3.zoom` at all. Should it be instead something like:

```
canvas.call(d3.pan()  // ??
              .on("zoom", pan));
```

A final alternative I can think of is that I should set no javascript handler for the scroll behavior, but just have a canvas element which is larger than `window.innerHeight`. Then maybe the browser would just take care of it for me? (trying this the naive way hasn't worked for me, so would love some help if this is the best option).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's some code which combines your two linked examples:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<canvas width="960" height="500"></canvas>
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
<script>

var canvas = d3.select("canvas"),
    context = canvas.node().getContext("2d"),
    width = canvas.property("width"),
    height = canvas.property("height"),
    radius = 2.5;

var points = d3.range(2000).map(phyllotaxis(10));

canvas.call(d3.zoom()
    .scaleExtent([1 / 2, 4])
    .on("zoom", zoomed))
    .on("wheel.zoom", pan);

drawPoints();

var currentTransform = d3.zoomIdentity;

function zoomed() {
  context.save();
  context.clearRect(0, 0, width, height);
  currentTransform = d3.event.transform;
  context.translate(currentTransform.x, currentTransform.y);
  context.scale(currentTransform.k, currentTransform.k);
  drawPoints();
  context.restore();
}

function pan() {
  context.save();
  context.clearRect(0, 0, width, height);
  currentTransform.x += d3.event.wheelDeltaX;
  currentTransform.y += d3.event.wheelDeltaY;
  context.translate(currentTransform.x, currentTransform.y);
  drawPoints();
  context.restore();
}

function drawPoints() {
  context.beginPath();
  points.forEach(drawPoint);
  context.fill();
}

function drawPoint(point) {
  context.moveTo(point[0] + radius, point[1]);
  context.arc(point[0], point[1], radius, 0, 2 * Math.PI);
}

function phyllotaxis(radius) {
  var theta = Math.PI * (3 - Math.sqrt(5));
  return function(i) {
    var r = radius * Math.sqrt(i), a = theta * i;
    return [
      width / 2 + r * Math.cos(a),
      height / 2 + r * Math.sin(a)
    ];
  };
}

</script>
```

Comment: is there another solution though? Would it be possible to make a very tall <canvas> element and then scroll the conventional way? Unfortunately, with as many elements as I have, the scroll animation is only getting a couple frames a second -- super choppy. Maybe this is unavoidable, but maybe not?

Comment: @AlexLenail, nothing stopping you from making the canvas as large as you want.  See [here for an example](http://plnkr.co/edit/mo8fhqQ0QFEaif9URWT9?p=preview).